# I have trouble webscraping the channels tab of a YouTube channel using python

Tags: python, web-scraping, youtube

I'm trying to webscrape the channels tab of this YouTube channel : https://www.youtube.com/c/mkbhd/channels

My goal is to extract the names of the channels mentionned (Which are highlighted in the image below) :
[image]

This is how my good looks like :

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


r = requests.get('https://www.youtube.com/c/mkbhd/channels')
html_content = r.text

soup = BeautifulSoup(html_content)
print(soup.prettify())
```

Reading the output which is too long to post here I was unable to see the name of a single channel in the channels tab. I wonder if the channels names are loaded dynamically and therefore I wouldn't be able to scrape it like I would normally be able to on a static website. Do you have a solution to this problem?

```
print(soup.find_all('a'))
```

I also tried finding all `<a>` tags in order to find the channels urls in the page but this was also not successful. It worked but there was not a single link that could potentially refer to a channel url.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks to me as though the best way to do this would be parsing the JSON in the HTML rather than using BeautiulSoup.

```
import requests, json


r = requests.get('https://www.youtube.com/c/mkbhd/channels')
html_content = r.text

content = json.loads((html_content.split('var ytInitialData = ')[1].split(';')[0]))

for item in content["contents"]["twoColumnBrowseResultsRenderer"]["tabs"][4]["tabRenderer"]["content"]["sectionListRenderer"]["contents"][0]["itemSectionRenderer"]["contents"][0]["gridRenderer"]["items"]:
    print(item["gridChannelRenderer"]["title"]["simpleText"])
```

It's not the prettiest but it works well.

**Output**:

```
20syl
Madeon
Jonathan Morrison
Brandon Havard
Vinh Dang
Austin Evans
Unbox Therapy
UrAvgConsumer
```

Comment: Thank you it does work but do you know of a cleaner way?

Comment: @Nassims Glad to hear it worked, you can tick the green check if you think this is your chosen answer. I don't think there will be a cleaner way personally, I'd use this. In my experience JSON is preferable to BeautifulSoup.